# Break Line for Label on ChartJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, stacked-chart

I'm having a problem with the Chart Js and need to insert two lines on the chart, preferably with different styles, but I am not able to do that.

Follow the link to an example of the problem and try what I did: https://jsfiddle.net/caioc/t6223vnu/

The label parameters I put the following code:

```
labels: ["teste", "teste \n LINE"]
```

Comment: I want the content after which it is written "teste" is in the second row and I not getting to do this

Comment: in fiddle to label the second bar is "teste LINE " as a label on the same line, the LINE should be written on the second line https://jsfiddle.net/caioc/t6223vnu/ @SantoshRamKunjir

Answer (score 0):

labels: [['(A)', 'Waking'], '(B)', '(C)', '(D)'],

This will display as A Walking in two lines.